# Is it possible to know that my app was started from a taskbar in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, taskbar

I'm coding using C++/MFC with WinAPIs and I was curious if it's possible to know that my app was started from a click on a taskbar icon (that was pinned there)?

PS. I need to know this to display a pop-up menu above my program's icon on the taksbar, pretty much like it happens after a right-click.

Comment: You know that you can add items to the existing jump list, right? Wouldn't that be a 1000x better than your proposed solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can know if you app was pinned and where normally.
I wouldn't reccoment it, but you can know that it's started from there by the position of the mouse.
This will not always work because there are keyboards that have buttons for task bar items.

Comment: ... for example, it's possible to run pinned applications with Win-1, Win-2, etc keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Yeah I ran into the same issue. What I'm curious to know, if there's an API to know the layoyt of the taskbar's pinned icons?